# How to create multiple instances for Singleton class

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, singleton, instance

I have created a Singleton class using lazy initialization method. That is the getInstance method is synchronized. But without changing the design pattern is there a way to create multiple instances of the Singleton class. Because changing the Singleton pattern will take lot of architectural changes. Please advice a way to create multiple instances. Please help in Java.

Comment: _without changing the design pattern is there a way to create multiple instances of the Singleton class_ I think you answered your own question here. No, there isn't.

Comment: Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Just make a public constructor?

Comment: ... or load the singleton with different peer-classloaders. A class loaded by an instances of a classloader is considered different to the same class loaded by a different classloader. This way you gain multiple instances of the same singleton instance - though this is a contradiction of the singleton pattern!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** I don't have the required reputation to add it as a comment hence adding it as an answer - as pointed out in the comments, it's a possible duplicate.

A little research and there you have it:

Reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064661/how-to-instantiate-a-singleton-multiple-times)

**Code**

```
class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton() {
    }
}

class Test {
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Constructor<MySingleton> constructor = MySingleton.class.getConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        MySingleton otherSingleton = constructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just copying an answer from another question as your own answer is bad practice here. Post a link in the comments instead, so it can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: How can use this implementation for a MySingleton constructor with parameters.Current method gives 'NoSuchMethodException'. If I am to use getDeclaredConstructor how should I use that?

Comment: Nopes.. I am getting NoSuchMethodException... Works fine with "getDeclaredConstructor()"

Comment: @user2625772 - Constructor<MySingleton> constructor = MySingleton.class.getDeclaredConstructor();

Comment: When I use getDeclaredConstructor() without passing any arguments it gives me an error. But when I pass the arguments that are there for Singleton constructor it again gives an error. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Singleton patten means only one instance is allowed. So there is no question of creating multiple instances.

Though there are some hacks and workarounds like `Serializing the Object and De Serializing` it back or `using different Class loaders` but again it violates the basic principle why Singleton pattern is created for.

Comment: what about reflection ?

Comment: @giorashc What about it?

Comment: @giorashc: That is why he wrote "allowed" and not "possible".

Comment: Yeah I edited my answer. There are always workaround but it is not what design pattern is intended for.

Comment: but the OP specifically states that he cannot touch the singleton so I believe he is aware for the definition of it

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux "So there is no question of creating multiple instances.". Yes there is ...

Comment: Cannot touch Vs. wouldn't touch.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have multiple instances of a class which can only have one instance by design.

You can, but it is no longer a singleton.  Treat it as a normal object which have multiple instances and the restriction is lifted.  How you do that depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the class behaviour. If the instance is well encapsulated, you can recreate what `getInstance` method does using reflection, I guess.